# If $F$ is algebraic over $K$ and $D$ is an intermediate and an integral domain, is $D$ a field?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I would imagine it would be as simple as showing that $D$ is finite since a finite integral domain is a field. I know that if $F$ is a finite extension of $K$, then $F$ is an algebraic extension of $K$. Is the converse true? That is, is the statement "if $F$ is an algebraic extension of $K$, then $F$ is a finite extension of $K$" true? That would in turn immediately imply that $D$ must be finite which concludes that $D$ is finite and a field.

Comment: Algebraic extensions are not necessarily finite. For example $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}$ (where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$) is of infinite degree.

Comment: So then what would be a better way to verify that $D$ is a field? This counter-example unravels my entire argument.

Comment: Finite integral domains are fields, but that is not really relevant here because in the world of field theory "finite extension" means "finite-dimensional extension" and doesn't imply that the extended field is finite: in the jargon, $\Bbb{C}$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can reduce it to the finite case as follows. Let $a \in D$ be nonzero, and note that $a$ is algebraic over $K$. Hence, if $f(x)=x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+c_0$ is its minimal polynomial over $K$, then
$$ -c_0a^{-1} = a^{n-1}+c_{n-1}a^{n-2}+\dots+c_1 \in D. $$
As $c_0$ is a unit in $D$, it follows that $a^{-1} \in D$. This shows that all nonzero elements of $D$ are units, hence it is a field.

Comment: I assume we are using the fact that since $a\in D\subset F$ then $a^{-1}$ exists and $f(a)a^{-1}$ = 0?

Comment: Yes! If you think about it, is the same idea as the usual proof for $F$ finite over $K$, but "one element at a time".